# Why is my plane clipping my OBJ?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I'm currently working on a project using three.js and react.

I have to load an OBJ and display it. Everything is working fine until i'm trying to add some more element to the scene just to make it more beautiful.

As soon as i'm adding another mesh, like a plane or a box (in this example it's a box), my OBJ is cut, and we only see the button of the pants. Can someone explain to me why it's happening ? I don't find any reason for a plane or a box to cut my obj.

[image: pants webgl]

[image]

Here is the two function i'm using for loading my object. I know that i'm not using setState when i should, it's just for kick prototype for now.

```
createPlane = (scene) => {
        var planeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
        const planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: '#E8E8E8', side: THREE.DoubleSide})
        this.setState({plane:new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial)}, () => {
            this.state.plane.frustumCulled = false;
            this.state.plane.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
            scene.add(this.state.plane)
        })
    }


 loadObj = (scene) => {
        //const loader = new OBJLoader()
        const mtlloader = new MTLLoader()
        const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader()
        textureLoader.load('models/jeans2_tex.png', (tex) => {
            tex.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            tex.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            //tex.repeat.set( 4, 4 );
            new OBJLoader().load('models/Jeans2_blue.OBJ', (object) => {
                    console.log('TEXTURE', tex)
                    console.log('OBJECT', object)
                    //let new_mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: tex, side: THREE.DoubleSide} )
                    let new_mat = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({map: tex, metalness: 0.1, roughness: 0.9})
                    object.position.y = -2.0
                    object.frustumCulled = false
                    object.children.map((child) => {
                        console.log('CHILD')
                        child.material = new_mat
                    })
                    this.setState({object: object}, () => {scene.add(this.state.object)})

                }, (xhr) => {
                    console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded')
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.log('AN error happened')
                }
            )
        })
```

Comment: This is just a stab in the dark, but are you sure you're not confusing the React framework when you do `this.setState({object: object});`? `object` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript and maybe when you set `plane` into the state, it overrides the previous `object`. Try `this.setState({jeans: object});`

Comment: @Marquizzo `Object` (capital O) is the reserved word, `object` (lower-case o) is fine.